# Do I need Croatian visa with Multiple entry Schengen with granted stay duration < less than intended stay in Schengen+Croatia?

Tags: visas, schengen, croatia

I am planning to travel to Austria, Hungary and Croatia (total 14 days), in the mentioned sequence. I was issued multiple entry Schengen visa ('C' visa) by Embassy of Austria with validity covering the entire duration of the trip.

But my visa mentions duration of stay as 10 days, whereas my total duration of intended stay is 14 days, which includes 7 days in Schengen (Austria + Hungary) & 7 days in Croatia.

Do I need separate Croatia visa since my duration of stay in Croatia is less than granted duration of stay (excluding no. of days stayed in Schengen), as per my Visa.

**[Edited to add]:**

The validity of my visa is for 21 days (15th May to 6th June). I land in Schengen on 15th May and exit from Schengen on 21st May. Afterwards, I go to Croatia & stay in Croatia from 21st to 28th May and then take flight back to my country India on 28th May.

The allowed duration of stay mentioned on my Visa is 10 days. My question is that if this allowed duration of 10 days covers only stay in Schengen (which in my case is 7 days) or is it supposed to cover my total stay (stay in Schengen of 7 days + stay in Croatia of 7 days)?

Answer (score 1):

From the readings I have done, I have to agree with phoog's comment.

The Croatian MFEA is very clear in the [requirements](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/) for entry in this case:

> All third-country nationals who are holders of valid Schengen documents, as well as national visas and residence permits of Bulgaria, Cyprus, and Romania do not require an additional (Croatian) visa for Croatia.

Additionally, further down the page they reiterate this (emphasis is mine):

> The ***period of validity*** of the above mentioned Schengen, Bulgarian, Cypriot, and Romanian documents must cover the duration of the transit or stay.

Period of validity "valid to and from" are different than "length of authorized stay" and I am sure they do not mention the latter in any text published on their site.

And finally, "period of validity" is mentioned in the original [legislation](http://www.mvep.hr/files/file/2014/140724-5652014eu-en.pdf) which established the recognition of Schengen visas for use in Croatia

> Article 4:
>
> - The ***period of validity*** of the documents referred to in Articles 2 and 3 shall cover the duration of the transit or stay.

Which leads me to conclude that in this case, though your authorized stay is over, you are within the period of validity and can therefore use it to enter and stay legally in Croatia as planned.

Answer (score -2):

According to their website,  *Third-country nationals who are holders of uniform visa (C) for two or multiple entries, valid for all Schengen Area Member States do not require a visa for transit or intended stays in the territory of Croatia not exceeding 90 days in any 180-day period*. It also states the following: *The period of validity of the above mentioned Schengen, Bulgarian, Cypriot, and Romanian documents must cover the duration of the transit or stay.* So I think a 10-day visa will not cover your stay in Croatia. A safe bet is to apply for a Croatian visa through their website.

I'm referring to this link: http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/

I hope this helps!

Comment: The period of validity of the visa in question does cover the duration of stay in Croatia, so it is not clear why you reach the conclusion that a Croatian visa is needed.